# How long is the interval for a ping that results in "Destination Host Unreachable"?

Tags: ping

Is there a set duration ping waits for returning "Destination Host Unreachable"? If I know the time when I issued a ping, I want to be calculate how long it took to get back my first ack.

```
From host-redacted.com (ip.redacted) icmp_seq=1006 Destination Host Unreachable
From host-redacted.com (ip.redacted) icmp_seq=1007 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from host-redacted.com (ip.redacted): icmp_seq=1008 ttl=64 time=977 ms
64 bytes from host-redacted.com (ip.redacted): icmp_seq=1009 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependant on your OS, but I believe a great many systems use `1000ms` as the default timeout for `ping`.

On windows, the `ping` command accepts a parameter `ping -w X` where X is the timeout in milliseconds.

On many linux distributions, you can use `ping -t X` to modify the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping):

> `-W timeout` Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absense of any responses, otherwise ping waits for two RTTs.

RTT = Round Trip Time. Seems like it does not have a set value but depend on your network config.

Answer (score 1):

"Destination host unreachable" indicates a routing problem, not a timeout problem: Some node between the sender and the destination *does not know how to route packets to that destination*. Waiting longer won't help with that, you have to diagnose or correct the routing problem.